# Unable to insert null in bytea field in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, blob

I am unable to insert a null value in my postgres database where the datatype is bytea(blob). This is my code snippet from java:

```
ps.setNull(++index, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
```

The bytea column is a nullable column. The following is the table description.

```
testdb=# \d+ plan 
                           Table "public.plan"
   Column    | Type  | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 

-------------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------

description | bytea |           | extended |              | 

Has OIDs: no
```

I am getting the following exception
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 11 INSERT INTO public.plan(description)  VALUES(NULL) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 11 INSERT INTO public.plan(description)  VALUES(NULL) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
This is the exception.

Comment: column "description" is of type bytea but expression is of type oid. How is it getting converted to oid.

Comment: Try `setObject(++index, null)` or `setNull(++index, Types.OTHER)`

Comment: Thanks man, it worked with setNull(++index, Types.OTHER). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres has two different "BLOB" types: `bytea`, which is essentially what the SQL standard defines as a `BLOB`. And "large objects" which is more or less a "pointer" to binary storage (it's still stored inside the DB).

The Postgres JDBC has always  treated "large objects" as the equivalent to `BLOB` (which I have never understood) and thus `ps.setNull(++index, java.sql.Types.BLOB);` makes the driver think you are dealing with a "large object" (aka "oid") column.

To overcome this, use

```
ps.setNull(++index, Types.OTHER);
```

alternatively you can use:

```
ps.setObject(++index, null);
```

Comment: One question remains, how portable are these solutions? For posterity: I've positively tested `ps.setObject(++index, null);` on PostgreSQL 10.10, Oracle 12.1, MySQL 8.0.18 and Derby 10.14.

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me:

```
ps.setNull(++index, Types.BINARY);
```